# Is there a way to do rotation in UIViewController without animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios4

Is there a way to enable rotation but without the animation as you turn the device from portrait to landscape?

I'm looking at:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

... but I don't see how I can set the "duration" property to 0 and thus eliminate the animation.  Perhaps there is a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the transform property of a UIView to rotate your view immediately :

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180.0);
yourView.transform = trans;
```

Hope it will help.

More information available [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGAffineTransform)